# SQL Server 2008: find all tables containing columns with specified name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know it is possible to select the tables which contain a specific column name with a query like:

```
SELECT t.name,
       c.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
   ON c.object_id=t.object_id 
WHERE c.name like '%colname%'
```

Is there a way to find the tables which contain 2 or more given columns?

To give an example, what I want to find is all tables that have the specific columns: student and teacher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group by the content that is unique and count the group content in the `having` clause

```
select t.name
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id 
where c.name in ('student','teacher')
group by t.name
having count(distinct c.name) = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

For example, I have a database named **Organisation**. I have more than one table where **tax_id** column is present.

Most of the time, we have to find such a column from the whole database. 
**The solution is provided below:**

```
select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%tax%'
```

There is no matter in query to database name which ever you just need to change willing **Column Name** and will found required result

**Search any value Like computer in whole database in which column and in which tables value computer exists**

For it first we need to write a store procedure then we reuse it for our search i got it from http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm very perfect result.
after executing store procedure we got required result as in given below image.
Image showing complete search result of keyword computer from whole database.
[image: Image showing complete search result of keyword computer from whole database]